# How to get the ip address of the computer which runs a web application in python

Tags: python, rest, ip, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a web API i would like to get the IP address of the computers which use my application. I have developed my API using python. And the users may be using any os.

I used this code to get the IP address but this does not give proper result in every platform.

```
socket.gethostbyname(gethostname())
```

Comment: Examples of which os you are having trouble with and what you are getting and what you are expecting would be helpful

Comment: I am using windows but my user may use any operating system so is it possible to get the ip address from those systems too

Comment: If some wants to downvote my question then atleast have the courtesy to provide the proper answer. If you have already come across such question atleast provide the link so that people like me can get solution for our problem. We ask such questions because we couldn't find the proper answer. Or if you feel the way of asking is wrong then tell us we will try to do better next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using netifaces library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces
Otherwise, it is very hard to get cross platform compatibility.

Examples from documentation:

```
>>> netifaces.interfaces()
['lo0', 'gif0', 'stf0', 'en0', 'en1', 'fw0']


>>> netifaces.ifaddresses('lo0')
{18: [{'addr': ''}], 2: [{'peer': '127.0.0.1', 'netmask': '255.0.0.0', 'addr': '127.0.0.1'}], 30: [{'peer': '::1', 'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff', 'addr': '::1'}, {'peer': '', 'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', 'addr': 'fe80::1%lo0'}]}
```

Comment: the documentation asks the user to install netifaces. My question is if I run this code on a web server will it work? I havent got a web server right now i will be getting one soon. Will it get the IP address of the users of my api. I am just a beginner with python web api

Comment: In your example code you use socket.gethostname(), which returns  address of the computer your run it on. So, I supposed you get your code run on user computers. netifaces is platform independent alternative to your code example.

Comment: @Eriks_Dobelis My doubt is this works because i have installed netifaces in my system but my end user wont have installed it so will it work then?